# I can draw the bullet

Tags: python

So I am creating a game, and for some reason my bullet doesn´t show in the screen. I don't know why, and I really need Help. Please!!!  I don't know what am I doing wrong. Can you try my code and help me? Maybe the problem is in the spryte, but I tried do change and it still didn't work.

Here is my code

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameStop = False

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

larguraTela = 800
alturaTela = 800

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((larguraTela, alturaTela))

pygame.display.set_caption('catch the coin')
player_sprite = pygame.image.load('ship_G.png').convert_alpha()
enemy_sprite = pygame.image.load('enemy_A.png').convert_alpha()
bullet_sprite = pygame.image.load('spaceMissiles_001.png').convert_alpha()

gameExit = False

userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = img
        self.vel = 0
        self.Right = False
        self.Left = False
        self.bullets = []

    def draw_self(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

    def movement(self, userInput):
        if userInput[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.Right = True
            self.Left = False
            self.x += self.vel
        if userInput[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.Left = True
            self.Right = False
            self.x += self.vel

    def receive_input(self):
        if self.Right:
            self.vel = 5
        elif self.Left:
            self.vel = -5
        else:
            self.vel = 0

    def shoot(self):
        if userInput[pygame.K_f]:
            bullet = Bullet(self.x, self.y, bullet_sprite)
            self.bullets.append(bullet)
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            bullet.move()

    def draw_bullets(self):
        for i in self.bullets:
            i.draw_self()

    def update(self):
        userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.receive_input()
        self.movement(userInput)
        self.draw_self()
        self.draw_bullets()

    def update_bullet(self):
        for bullet in player.bullets:
            bullet.draw_self()



class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.image = img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vel = 10

    def draw_self(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def movement(self):
        self.rect.y += self.vel
        if self.rect.y > alturaTela:
            self.rect.y = self.y
            enemy.draw_self()

    def uptade(self):
        enemy.draw_self()
        enemy.movement()

class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.image = img
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw_self(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))




enemy = Enemy(400, -40, enemy_sprite)

player = Player(0, 400, player_sprite)


def draw_game():
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    for bullet in player.bullets:
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    pygame.display.update()


while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            gameExit = True


    draw_game()
    player.shoot()

    player.update()
    enemy.uptade()
    player.draw_bullets()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what is the current problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some troubles with creating bullets, u wasn't actually checking correct user input here:

```
   def shoot(self):
    if userInput[pygame.K_f]:
        bullet = Bullet(self.x, self.y, bullet_sprite)
        self.bullets.append(bullet)
    for bullet in self.bullets:
        bullet.move()
```

I slightly changed some things, hope it works for you.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameStop = False

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

larguraTela = 800
alturaTela = 800

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((larguraTela, alturaTela))

pygame.display.set_caption('catch the coin')
player_sprite = pygame.image.load('ship_G.png').convert_alpha()
enemy_sprite = pygame.image.load('enemy_A.png').convert_alpha()
bullet_sprite = pygame.image.load('spaceMissiles_001.png').convert_alpha()

gameExit = False

userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = img
        self.vel = 0
        self.Right = False
        self.Left = False
        self.bullets = []

    def draw_self(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

    def movement(self, userInput):
        if userInput[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.Right = True
            self.Left = False
            self.x += self.vel
        if userInput[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.Left = True
            self.Right = False
            self.x += self.vel

    def receive_input(self):
        if self.Right:
            self.vel = 5
        elif self.Left:
            self.vel = -5
        else:
            self.vel = 0

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.x, self.y, bullet_sprite)
        self.bullets.append(bullet)

    def draw_bullets(self):
        for i in self.bullets:
            i.move()
            i.draw_self()

    def update(self):
        userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.receive_input()
        self.movement(userInput)
        self.draw_self()
        self.draw_bullets()

    def update_bullet(self):
        for bullet in player.bullets:
            bullet.draw_self()



class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.image = img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vel = 10

    def draw_self(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def movement(self):
        self.rect.y += self.vel
        if self.rect.y > alturaTela:
            self.rect.y = self.y
            enemy.draw_self()

    def uptade(self):
        enemy.draw_self()
        enemy.movement()

class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.image = img
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self):
        self.y -= 5

    def draw_self(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))




enemy = Enemy(400, -40, enemy_sprite)

player = Player(0, 400, player_sprite)


def draw_game():
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    pygame.display.update()


while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            gameExit = True

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_f]:
        player.shoot()

    draw_game()


    player.update()
    enemy.uptade()
    player.draw_bullets()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```